# Can you perform a PERMANOVA analysis on nested data?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, permutation-test, vegan, permanova

I've found no answer in the papers I have read regarding PERMANOVAs or on the web so I'm really hoping someone could help me answer this question. An example would be testing PERMANOVA on dissimilarity matrix Y by effects C, B, and A, wherein C is nested in B, and B is nested in A. I'm using the `adonis` function in the R `vegan` package.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is based on the `adonis` function in the `vegan` package for R. Nesting can enter a permanova in two ways: your model and your permutation structure (the `strata` parameter).

In your model formula, nesting is simply interaction as specified in R with the forward slash or colon (`A/B/C` or `A:B:C`); you are specifying that the effect of `C` should differ based on the value of `B` and `A`. This is like a fixed effect. Also note that forward slash differs from colon in that it includes terms for all layers in the nesting hierarchy: `A+A:B+A:B:C`.

With `strata=A:B`, you limit your permutations to be between only those samples with the same levels of `A` and `B`. This implicitly treats data from each `A:B` interaction level as coming from the separate distributions/having disparate error structure. It is therefore somewhat similar to a random effect.

Depending on what your question is, you might include your nesting in either place or in both (see link in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/238962/61689)).